# ActiveStorage to upload large base64 encoded string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

If I have an image that was edited/generated using JavaScript on the client (for example, a cropped photo or the result of a canvas drawing), is there a way to upload it using ActiveStorage?

It would typically be a large string containing `"<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,...=='>"` that is stored in a JavaScript variable, not a file.

Answer (score 18):

You can do something like this:

```
decoded_data = Base64.decode64(params[:base64].split(',')[1])
resource.image = { 
  io: StringIO.new(decoded_data),
  content_type: 'image/jpeg',
  filename: 'image.jpg'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a gem for this.

Take a look at https://github.com/rootstrap/active-storage-base64

It's pretty straight forward after installing the gem.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveStorageSupport::SupportForBase64
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_base64_attached :avatar
end
```

Assigning to an instance of your model is done by:

```
base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,[base64 data]'
user.avatar = {data: base64}
```

Answer (score 4):

I did it without the gem.

```
          Model.create!(
            product: product,
            attachment: { 
              io: StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(params[:product][:base_64_image].split(',')[1])),
              content_type: 'image/jpeg',
              filename: 'image.jpeg'
            }
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Active Storage has currently no native support for that.

Maybe [this Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32208) has further information helpful to you.

We have implemented Data URI uploads with Shrine (and its [DataURI Plugin](https://shrinerb.com/rdoc/classes/Shrine/Plugins/DataUri.html)) and are waiting until there is a proper way to do this with Active Storage before we will migrate.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Diego Carrion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303924/diego-carrion)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58868717/3437900)

I did like this.

```rb
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_one_attached :signature
  ...
```

```rb
module Api
  module V1
    class BookingsController < Api::V1::ApiController
    ...
    
      def confirm_hire_details
        booking = current_user.bookings.find(params[:id])

        if booking.update(booking_params.merge(
          {
            signature: signature_decoded
          }
        ))
          ...
        else
          ...
        end
      end

      private

      def signature_decoded
        decoded_data = Base64.decode64(params[:signature].split(',')[1])
        {
          io:           StringIO.new(decoded_data),
          content_type: 'image/jpeg',
          filename:     "signature-#{Time.current.to_i}.jpg"
        }
      end
```